# What is an efficient way of collaborating on notification system with a team?

Tags: planning, email

I work as a product owner on a webapp P.O.C
I need to work on the notification system with a team that **is not accustomed to Gitlab or other DevOps tools**.

What would be an efficient (and preferably open source) tool we could use for:

1. Identifying Process Flow Step (Trigger Time, Conditions, recipient...)
2. Collaborate on writing the template for each notification (header, footer, content...)
3. Maintaining an updated knowledge of our notification system and keep track of team suggestion

PS : For the moment we are working with google sheet and I think it is only a short-term solution.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It could be useful to edit the question to clarify whenever you want a "software to communicate with a team over a general goal like doing a new system" (it seems so from your preamble); or if your teem need to discuss the best notification system to be implemented on an already-existing software/app (it seems so from the body). If yes, I don't understand how is it possible to develop such "new notification tool" based on "Google Sheet", since to me Google Sheet is not a development environment but just something like LibreOffice, to collaborate on a document. Thank you for your clarification

Comment: In short, I don't understand if this is a question related to software development (so, receive recommendations for a notification system to be integrated into your already-existing solution (an app) to be presented by your team); or a question related to project management, so, receive recommendations to communicate / "notify" stuff to your team, to achieve some goals to be clarified. Sorry if I seem confused. Feel free to just edit the question to kill my confusion in key points. Note that I'm a developer and so probably I'm understanding something different than your professional context

Comment: Hello, thank you for your question. I will try to clarify my initial post here. 
I need a tool to discuss the best notification system to be implemented on an already-existing software--> specifically a tool that can be handled by non-dev teams as I will collect the opinion of users, project managers etc.
Today it's as simple as a google sheet with on one side the screenshot of the current notification / on the other side the new content that the team would like to implement, with notes and comment a bit "everywhere" on the doc
But I feel like surely we can do better. Thank you in advance

Comment: OK thanks. If you need a simple but powerful too to show graphical proof of concepts, I think this tool could be useful and is also Open Source:
https://penpot.app/

If you would like similar answers, I probably recommend in improving a bit the question to be a bit "less focused on notifications", since as I see you are probably OK with something very generic like Google Sheet that is not focused on "notification systems". So that is why probably other people have not suggested anything.